# Moodle - "Exception - Call to undefined method admin_setting_configduration::set_validate_function()" after update

Tags: ubuntu, syntax-error, moodle

I was upgrading my moodle server from version something like 3.9.x to 3.11.x, can't remember the exact versions.

I think what was happening was, while the server was updating, some plugin didn't update because of Errors, and eve tho that should have lead me back to the updating tab to fix this, I simply got redirected to my homepage again.

After that, everytime I tried to access Site Adminitration, I was getting this message:
[Picture of Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naWmb.png)

Googling did nothing, as nobody sems to have a similar Problem, at least not with this function.

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

With any such issue, your first step should be to enable debugging on your site, in order to get a full error message.

You can follow the instructions here: https://docs.moodle.org/311/en/Debugging to enable debugging.

As you don't have access to your site admin user interface, you'll need to enable debugging in your config.php, with the following lines:

```
$CFG->debug = (E_ALL | E_STRICT);
$CFG->debugdisplay = 1;
```

Once that is done, you should be able to track down the plugin that is causing the error - you will then have to either remove that plugin from the code or add a new version that is compatible with Moodle 3.11.

However, looking at the code ( https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/master/lib/adminlib.php#L3909 ) it appears that set_validate_function() was introduced in Moodle 3.10 (and is still present in Moodle 4.0), so it seems very odd that you would get an error about it missing in Moodle 3.11.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick answer. I've enabled debugging and saw massive list full of error messages. I've linked them all in this Imgur Post.

https://imgur.com/a/6ItS42p

Since I am relativley new to Administrating a moodle server, could you please give me hints on how to fix at least some of this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks to me like the code is in a bit of a mess. If you are just using Moodle without any plugins, then I suggest to move all of the code to a separate folder, then download a fresh copy of the code. If you have plugins, the do the same, but put the latest copies of those plugins into the new code, before continuing.